# Typescript & Immutable - Trouble with exported immutable map

Tags: typescript, immutable.js

I'm basically trying to import a "module" that I created for my app, and have access to a variable which should be present in the app, as well as some helping functions.

**My module below:**

```
import * as immutable from 'immutable';

const treeduxTrunk = immutable.Map();

export function setBranch( branchName: string, twigStruct: Object ) {
    treeduxTrunk.set( branchName, twigStruct );
} 

export default treeduxTrunk;
```

**My app file:**

```
import trunk     = require('../treedux/lib/treeduxTrunk');

treeduxTrunk.setBranch( 'route1', { 
    users: 'nothing',
    products: 13
});

console.log( treeduxTrunk.default );
```

The current result is:

**Map {size: 0, _root: undefined, __ownerID: undefined, __hash: undefined, __altered: false}**

I was expecting it have size greater than 0, to be accurate I was expecting 1.

Any idea on what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,

TF

Answer (score 0):

`set` [returns a value, not updating the immutable map](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/set).

Try this:

```
export function setBranch( branchName: string, twigStruct: Object ) {
    treeduxTrunk = treeduxTrunk.set( branchName, twigStruct );
}
```